# netsh advfirewall firewall outbound rule not blocking connections

Tags: windows, firewall, system-administration, windows-firewall

I am creating an outbound connection blocking firewall rule for MS Edge browser in Windows 11 with the following command:

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="rulename" dir=out action=block profile=any program="c:/program files (x86)/path/to/msedge"`

I am able to see that the rule has been created but when I tried to load webpages in ms edge, it does not block the connection to the website.

What is the correct way to block an application so that it cannot make connections to the internet (especially apps like MS Edge)?

Edit: Output of `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="msedge_o" verbose`

```
Rule Name:                            msedge_o
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled:                              Yes
Direction:                            Out
Profiles:                             Domain,Private,Public
Grouping:
LocalIP:                              Any
RemoteIP:                             Any
Protocol:                             Any
Edge traversal:                       No
Program:                              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
InterfaceTypes:                       Any
Security:                             NotRequired
Rule source:                          Local Setting
Action:                               Block
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your command. It works fine at my test system.

The conclusion is, the *real* command you've issued probably has a typo or an inaccuracy.
My bet goes, you've omitted the file extension `.exe`.

This will shift the limit for the rule to the not existing file `msedge` and `msedge.exe` will not be seen as the target of the rule.

Check the current state of your rule:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="RULENAME" verbose
```

*(replace "RULENAME" with the real name of the rule)*

... and update your question by the output of the command.

Then remove the rule and try this command:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="TEST: Block EDGE" dir=out action=block profile=any program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
```

Test your Edge Browser and compare the differences old/new version of the rule.

#### Update

Your update shows the rule in a proper state. But your problem persists.

###### Possibility 1: You do not use an "edge" installed at the default place:

1. Open the Task-Manager (Key-ShortCut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>)
2. In the tab "Processes" search the currently running "Microsoft Edge" (start it if not present).
3. Right-click the "Edge" processes one by one and choose "Properites".
4. There you compare the path and name of the process with the details of the netsh rule. – They have to be identical.

###### Possibility 2: There is an intermediate "tool" installed locally

This can be a local proxy / VPN / family safety / browser security by an anti-malware suite / real malware / or something similar.

Check the detail with

```
netstat -bn
```

or get more sophisticated tools like the `TCPview` from the [Sysinternals Suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/). Preferably you install the whole suite, but you can get TCPview as a single download.
("Installation" is done by extracting the ZIP to a folder.)

By these tools you should check if Edge is connecting directly to the internet server or to a local process.

Comment: I have added the verbose rule

Comment: So your question is solved?

Comment: not really, even after trying your command, edge is still able to connect to the internet and load websites.

Comment: Do you have any local proxy or VPN software installed? Or some "Family Safety" software?